# cv2.imread function is very slow

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

hello i want to access only 4000 images in google colab from google drive folder so that i can convert into numpy array and resize the images but the cv2.imread function is taking too much time almost 25 to 30 minutes and i have to re-run the code with i login again to google colab so is there any way to fast my cv2.imread function or is there any way that i can save mh google colab so i do not need to re-run the code again.

```
images = os.listdir('path_to_images')
path_to_image = 'path_to_images/'
numpy_list = []
for i in images:
  img = cv2.imread(path_to_image+i)#this function take alot of time
  img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))
  img = np.array(img)
  numpy_list.append(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function takes a lot of time because it is usually slow to read large quantities of small files on google colab (or any other service with limited disk iops). In addition, the actual image decoding is an expensive operation and might take a long time if the images are large.

Since you are already converting the images to numpy arrays, you can store all images as one large file which will then load much faster.

Save to file:

```py
with open('images.npy', 'wb') as file:
    np.save(file, numpy_list)
```

Load from file:

```py
with open('images.npy', 'rb') as file:
    numpy_list = np.load(file)
```

The images will be stored in one file and should load much faster. The downside is, that the images are now stored uncompressed (as raw numpy arrays) and will occupy more space on the disk. You may want to look at numpy [savez_compressed](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) function to store compressed numpy arrays.